# Storing Unicode and special characters in MySQL tables

Tags: java, mysql, unicode

My current requirement is to store Unicode and other special characters, such as double quotes in MySQL tables. For that purpose, as many have suggested, we should use Apache's **StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()** method. The problem is, although this method does replace special characters with their respective unicodes (\uxxxx), the MySQL table stores them as uxxxx and not \uxxxx. Due to this, when I try to decode it while fetching from the database, **StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()** fails (since it cannot find the '\').

Here are my questions:

1. Why is it happening (that is, '\' are skipped by the table).
2. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Unicode "codepoints" (`\uxxxx`), use UTF8.

Dont' use any special functions.  Instead announce that everything is UTF-8 (`utf8mb4` in MySQL).

See [*Best Practice*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

(If you are being provided `\uxxxx`, then you are stuck with converting to utf8 first.  If your real question is on how to convert, then ask it that way.)
`